# How many tickets do I need?

Tags: transit

If I book a ticket online Bucharest-Tirana with a stop in Turkey, do I get 2 tickets or just one? Do I have the whole ticket or do I have to check-in again in Turkey?

Comment: I think that you actually wanted to ask a different question: If when you buy a ticket online, whether you need to a) re-check your luggage, b) leave the "airside" of the airport in Turkey (which may require a visa depending on your nationality, or c) what happens if you miss your flight. Re-checking in can usually be done airside and is no problem at all.

Comment: you don't get paper tickets any more. An electronic record is created. Or maybe two. You don't care. At some point there will be boarding passes generated (and usually printed) - exactly when and where depends on your airline and airport. Please add these details to your question to make it answerable.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Unfortunately, it is unclear what you are asking. Presumably, this is for a flight as opposed to rail travel, but I'm not sure what you mean by *whole ticket*, for example. Could you [edit] your post to explain why you think you should/shouldn't/must/mustn't make a single booking as opposed to two?